# Problemas com Adapter no SearchView

Tags: android

Galera, o negocio é o seguinte. Em minha app, ao abri-la você tem uma ActivityPrincipal, nesta Activity eu tenho um ViewPagerAdapter que mostra três Abas(Vamos chama-las de aba-1, aba-2 e aba-3, cada uma com o seu fragment).
 Cada Aba Carrega uma lista usando o RecycleView. Os dados destas listas vem a partir do meu webservice. 
Até ai tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

Na ultima aba (Aba-3) é onde habilito na minha toolbar (que esta funcionando como actionBar) a pesquisa utilizando o SearchView.
 A ActivitySearch, responsável por listar os dados referentes a pesquisa, é basicamente o mesmo RecycleView e adapter que o utilizado na Aba-3, e é ai que começa meu problema. 
Vou explicar.

Quando clico no icone de pesquisa, em minha toolbar(que esta agindo como actionBar), ele abre um campo na própria actionBar para que eu possa digitar o que será pesquisa.
 Assim que eu digito e pressiono Enter(estou usando o emulador Genymotion), novamente uma pesquisa ao meu webservice é feita e retorna uma lista.Essa lista é passada para o adaptador do meu RecycleView, que se encarrega de mostrar os items na tela.
 O que acontece é que meu WebService retorna um JSON com dois objetos, mas o RecicleView só mostra o ultimo.
Ou seja, se eu fizer uma pesquisa que retorne 10 objetos, meu RecicleView só mostra 9, ignorando sempre o primeiro retornado. Lembrado que a mesma lista funciona de maneira correta quando vou até a Aba-3.

Alguem sabe por onde começar?

Comment: Como está sendo feita essa pesquisa no código?

Comment: Cara, na minha SearhActivity, eu estou preenchendo meu adaptador com dados vindo do meu WebService. Mas hoje fiz um adaptador bem simples que é preenchido por uma List< PojoTeste>, feita da forma mais simples possível, só pata eu ter noção se o problema  poderia estar vindo da maneira como preencho a lista a partir do WebService, mas infelizmente o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Não consigo intender, quando faço a pesquisa que retorna por exemplo 5 itens, o adaptador do meu RecycleView chama certinho 5 vezes o evento onCreateViewHolder e onBindViewHolder, mas na hora que o RecycleView aparece na tela, ele sempre ignora o primeiro item, mostrando só 4.